# maxDate in Material UI MobileDatePicker doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I don't know how to use `maxDate` prop in `MobileDatePicker` component. If I try to use `maxDate={new Date()}`, I am able to change date after current date.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-platform-c2qbs?file=/src/App.js)

```
<MobileDatePicker
          label="A Title"
          inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
          openTo="month"
          views={["year", "month"]}
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          renderInput={(props) => (
            <TextField id="date-picker-mobile" margin="normal" {...props} />
          )}
          OpenPickerButtonProps={{
            "aria-label": "change date"
          }}
          maxDate={new Date()}
        />
```

Comment: Tried on mobile, your picker is working, even if you can still select a future date than today, the picker will return an error and reset to today date at next render. Guess that this MobileDatePicker is different than typical pickers and don’t disable future dates

Comment: @poPaTheGuru what error it throws? I don't see any error.

Comment: My bad, it does not throw an explicit error, but like an error helper, the field goes red, that’s what i was saying by error

Comment: @poPaTheGuru `DatePicker` v3 doesn't allow you to select date after maxDate and `MobileDatePicker` v4 just underlines input? I don't understand why it's like this. Thanks for comment anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the default [`maxDate`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/blob/f8e7333d0a79ebb23011837ea9187cd0585da3e9/lib/src/constants/prop-types.ts#L18) value which is set by material-ui when you don't provide one:

```
export const defaultMaxDate = new Date('2099-12-31') as unknown;
```

which is nothing but a date object, hence `maxDate={new Date()}` is also correct. I tried your sandbox and it is working. When I selected a date after today's date, there is a **red underline** indicating the error:

[image: error-snapshot]

#### Update:

Check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-meadow-hvujb?file=/src/App.jsx) and [this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-dream-o7oojxx1pq?from-embed).

This code (from above sandbox) works perfectly i.e. won't even let you select a date after `maxDate`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <DatePicker
      value={selectedDate}
      onChange={handleDateChange}
      maxDate={new Date()}
    />
  );
}
```

PS: I am testing on web (not on mobile) and it is working fine. So, i can't say the difference between `MobileDatePicker` (from your question) and `DatePicker` (from the sandboxes above). Also, I found no documentation regarding `MobileDatePicker` at https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker

Comment: Your answer seems like the only one which is correct. It's really strange that `DatePicker` v3 doesn't allow you to select date after maxDate. `MobileDatePicker` v4 just indicates error.

Comment: I get it. There are v3 and v4-alpha versions. But, have you found any documentation for `MobileDatePicker`?

Comment: Found the source code for v4 - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/tree/v4.0.0-alpha.12/lib/src, and you are right, validation is not perfect i.e. it should not let us select a date after `maxDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify what date you want like so (Year, Month, Day):

```
maxDate={new Date(2019, 11, 24)}
```

Also, note that January is 0 and December is 11 in the Javascript land :D

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Date without arguments returns current date https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_current

Answer (score -1):

just add the date like this:

```
maxDate="02-21-2021"
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: yes cause I provide the current date which is today 21 February 2021 but If you pass the date as mm/dd/yyyy it will work.

Comment: ok I tried `maxDate="02/21/2021"` and it doesn't change anything

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.